# Profiling Rendering of WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, render, profiler, ui-thread

### Timeline in Profiler of Visual Studio

[image: Timeline in Profiler of Visual Studio]

I want to analyze my wpf application, but im having some problems with interpreting the results of the Visual Studio timeline profiler. The rendering process starts at second 30, which is clearly seeable in the screenshot. The weird thing for me is, that the screen of my application shows again up after 120 seconds. What happens in the time period which I marked with the questionmarks?

Has this anything to do with the fact that there is an UI-Thread and a Rendering-Thread in WPF?

The CompositionTarget.Rendering event is not fired during the time period which I marked with questionsmarks, so the rendering thread cant be finished.

Comment: Maybe look into the RedGate Performance Profiler. I think this is much better, maybe you can get a trial.